# multiple tqdm progress bars when using joblib parallel

Tags: multiprocessing, joblib, tqdm

I’ve a function:

```
def func(something):
    for j in tqdm(something):
        ...
```

which is called by:

```
joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=4)((joblib.delayed)(s) for s in something_else)
```

Now, this creates 4 overlapping tqdm progress bars. Is it possible to get 4 separate ones that update independently?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I was sent [this](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/407#issuecomment-322932800) discussion by a friend in which a much cleaner solution is provided. I wrote a quick performance test to make sure that the lock does not cause the threads to block each other. There was no performance hit even when updating bars every millisecond. I recommend that you use that solution instead.

The previous answer has been removed.