# How can I change this code to make the progress bars appear for each file and the iteration be each loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, tqdm

I am struggling with getting `tqdm`'s progress bar to stay and update as opposed to write to a new line. Note: I am using `multiprocessing` to parallelize my code, and `tqdm` is inside the function I am parallelizing.

I added a `print` statement so the files will all appear in my terminal when running the program. Reproducible example below:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def run_file_analysis(text):
    cool = []
    for i in tqdm(range(0, 10), position = 0, leave = True, desc = f'Text : {text}'):
        print('')
        cool.append(i)
        time.sleep(1)

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
ls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(run_file_analysis)(i) for i in ls)
```

Current output: 
[image]

The desired output would be the ten text objects - 1, 2, 3, ... , 10 and a corresponding updating progress bar for each. Not 100 different ones. I have tried following many stackoverflow questions relating to the topic of `tqdm` and `multiprocessing` integration, but none of them are as straightforward as I would like them to be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: Try running it. The displays will be all over the place and the progress bar will not be updating in a single line.

Comment: I don't want to run it. You should explain the problem in the question.

Comment: I did. Look at the first sentence :)

Comment: clearly your description is not enough, please add some readable outputs from your program, or the error you are getting with the desired output

Comment: Ok, what are you having a hard time understanding? I want to make this extremely readable. I will add the desired output and 'error'.

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of what you expected as output, and what you get instead. For example, it is not clear to me whether you expect to see one progress bar, or ten (one for each parallel process).

Comment: Ok. Did this help? I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: This is much better.

Comment: Awesome! Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: No, but I found this other question which seems to be about a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57112314/multiple-tqdm-progress-bars-when-using-joblib-parallel

Comment: Yes, that question is definitely the same type of question, but when I tried following the git issue, it did not work out for me.

Comment: why did you add the `print('')`? From what I understand so far, you want the progress bars to update in place, right? but the `print` statement adds a new line at each iteration thus `tqdm` has to write the progress bar on the next line each time. I don't know much about `tqdm`, but that would be my guess.

Comment: As stated, the print was added to ensure that all the inputs (text 1 through text 10) showed up in the terminal. Without the print there would be only one bar written over itself multiple times as we loop through the list. I definitely don't think print should be there, but at least this way I can see the progress of each one individually.

Comment: You’re putting the progress bars at fixed `position=0` so they are bound to overlap - as the thread number is passed as `text`, use `position=int(text)` might work but the real solution is probably to pass the thread number into it as an additional parameter to `text`. And yes remove the `print(‘’)`.

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work. Can you provide me with a working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, you don't want to add an extra new line with the print statement.
Instead you want to use the position argument in tqdm.
The use case for different threads is even mentioned in the [docs](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/).

```
position : int, optional
  Specify the line offset to print this bar (starting from 0)
  Automatic if unspecified. Useful to manage multiple bars at once (eg, from threads).
```

Currently, this argument is set to 0, so it will start the progress bar each time new. Instead you want to use the number of the thread. Because of simplicity, you can convert the given text to an integer and use this. But this is not recommended for production.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def run_file_analysis(text):
    cool = []
    for i in tqdm(range(0, 10), position=int(text), leave=True, desc = f'Text : {text}'):
        cool.append(i)
        time.sleep(1)

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
ls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(run_file_analysis)(i) for i in ls)
```

If the text's can not directly converted to integer, 'enumerate' can be used an the index can be passed to the function.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


def run_file_analysis(text, job_number):
    cool = []
    for i in tqdm(range(0, 10), position=job_number, leave=True, desc = f'Text : {text}'):
        cool.append(i)
        time.sleep(1)

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
ls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(run_file_analysis)(text, i) for i, text in enumerate(ls))
```

**Edit:**

Some raceconditions can be reduced by setting `prefer='threads'` to the Parallel constructor:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, prefer="threads")(delayed(run_file_analysis)(text, i) for i, text in enumerate(ls))
```

Comment: This works only because text can be converted to an integer, what if text was a string  like 'a'. 'b', 'c', 'd'. Sorry about the follow-up question. The files are not integer strings in the case I am trying to solve. I guess I can use `enumerate`

Comment: @DarkDrassher34, Yes, enumerate is the way to go. I updated my answer, to provide a possible solution.

Comment: Hmmm. That did not work. Did you try out your solution?

Comment: @DarkDrassher34 Can you describe what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It adds more than just the ten bars. Some of them appear twice.

Comment: @DarkDrassher34 I forgot to set the leave parameter to True. This ensures that all traces of the progressbar  are kept upon termination of iteration. I added it in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208994/discussion-between-darkdrassher34-and-querenker).